# Running mvn -pl Setup exec:exec gives error

Tags: maven, sikuli

After running `mvn clean install`, when I try to run `mvn -pl setup exec:exec` I get the following error:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>  
> [INFO] 
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
> [INFO] Building sikulixsetup 1.1.1 
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (default-cli) @
>   sikulixsetup --- 
> [debug] RunTimeINIT: global init: entering as:
>   SETUP 
> [debug] RunTimeINIT: ScreenDevice 0 has (0,0) --- will be
>   primary Screen(0) 
> [debug] RunTimeINIT: Monitor 0: (0, 0) 1600 x
>   900 
> [debug] RunTimeINIT: runs as sikulixsetup-1.1.1-forsetup.jar
>   in:
>   C:\Users\bhowmik\Downloads\TEST_NIGHTLY\SikuliX-2014-master\Setup\target
>   
> [debug] RunTimeINIT: folder target detected - supposing Maven
>   project: C:\Users\bhowmik\Downloads\TEST_NIGHTLY\SikuliX-2014-master
>   ***** show environment for SETUP (build 201605140512) user.home: C:\Users\bhowmik user.dir (work dir):
>   C:\Users\bhowmik\Downloads\TEST_NIGHTLY\SikuliX-2014-master\Setup
>   user.name: bhowmik java.io.tmpdir: C:\Users\bhowmik\AppData\Local\Temp
>   running 64Bit on Windows (6.1) in Maven project from some jar java
>   8-64 version 1.8.0_91-b14 vm 25.91-b14 class 52.0 arch amd64 app data
>   folder: C:\Users\bhowmik\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix libs folder: null
>   executing jar:
>   C:\Users\bhowmik\Downloads\TEST_NIGHTLY\SikuliX-2014-master\Setup\target\sikulixsetup-1.1.1-forsetup.jar
>   *** classpath dump sikulix   0: /C:/Users/bhowmik/Downloads/TEST_NIGHTLY/SikuliX-2014-master/Setup/target/sikulixsetup-1.1.1-forsetup.jar
>   *** classpath dump end
>   ***** show environment end 
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: global init: leaving 
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: initAPI: entering 
> [debug]
>   RunTimeSETUP: resourceList: enter 
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP:
>   resourceLocation: (class org.sikuli.setup.RunSetup) /Lib/sikuli
>   
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: resourceList: having jar:
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/bhowmik/Downloads/TEST_NIGHTLY/SikuliX-2014-master/Setup/target/sikulixsetup-1.1.1-forsetup.jar!/Lib/sikuli
>   
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: files exported: 7 from: Lib/sikuli to: 
>   C:\Users\bhowmik\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli 
> [debug]
>   RunTimeSETUP: initAPI: leaving 
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: exists libs
>   folder at:
>   C:\Users\bhowmik\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs_201605140512
>   
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: libs folder empty or has wrong content
>   
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: now exporting libs
>   *** classpath dump   0: /C:/Users/bhowmik/Downloads/TEST_NIGHTLY/SikuliX-2014-master/Setup/target/sikulixsetup-1.1.1-forsetup.jar
>   *** classpath dump end 
> [error] RunTimeSETUP:  *** terminating: libs to export not found on above classpath:
>   /sikulixlibs/windows/libs64 
> [debug] RunTimeSETUP: final cleanup
>   
> [debug] FileManager: deleteFileOrFolder:
>   C:\Users\bhowmik\AppData\Local\Temp\Sikulix_387398274 
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
> [INFO] Total time: 3.279 s 
> [INFO] Finished at:
>   2016-05-14T11:10:34+05:30 
> [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/153M 
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (default-cli) on
>   project sikulixsetup: Command execution failed. Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1 ]

Comment: You might get more lucky with this question on https://launchpad.net/sikuli

Comment: Yes, its working now after the new fix .